# Socket server running other code and sending updates to clients

Tags: python, sockets

This may have been already answered but did not find anything or dont know what to search for. I have a socket server threaded for multiple clients (code below) and want the server to run code (ie. check the status of something) and then send a message to the clients. How do I go about doing this?

To clarify, I need to learn how to add a asynchronous task to this code so it can do checking and send a message to the clients if it needs to

Example: while there are clients connected I want the server to continually check a log file and if it changes and if so I want it to send a message to the clients

**Server.py**(working code)

```
from socket import *
import thread

BUFF = 1024
HOST = '127.0.0.1'# must be input parameter @TODO
PORT = 9999 # must be input parameter @TODO
def response(key):
    return 'Server response: ' + key

def handler(clientsock,addr):
    while 1:
        data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
        if not data: break
        print repr(addr) + ' recv:' + repr(data)
        clientsock.send(response(data))
        print repr(addr) + ' sent:' + repr(response(data))
        if "close" == data.rstrip(): break # type 'close' on client console to close connection from the server side

    clientsock.close()
    print addr, "- closed connection" #log on console

if __name__=='__main__':
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversock.bind(ADDR)
    serversock.listen(5)
    while 1:
        print 'waiting for connection... listening on port', PORT
        clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
        print '...connected from:', addr
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, addr))
```

Comment: What issue are you facing with this code? Where r u stuck?

Comment: @drt The code above works, I just dont know how to add a method or function that runs at the same time that would be able to send a message to a client if it needs to. For example, if the cpu usage goes over 50% send a message to the clients saying so.

Comment: did u try telnet This link http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/ should help you

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code server.py and this works for sending a status change message when log file changes.

```
import socket
import sys
import time
from thread import *
 
HOST = 'localhost'   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 9999 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
 
#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
     
print 'Socket bind complete'
 
#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string
    data = conn.recv(1024)
     
    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:
        logfile = open("serverlog.txt","r")
        #Receiving from client
        logfile.seek(0,2)
        while True:
            line = logfile.readline()
            if not line:
                time.sleep(0.1) # Sleep briefly
                continue
            reply = 'File Changed...Your Data' + data
            break
        conn.sendall(reply)
    
    #came out of loop
    conn.close()
 
#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
     
    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))
 
s.close()
```

To test it run this server.py in one command prompt and keep it open. something like this

```
> python server.py 
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
```

And run a simple telnet from other cmd prompt to verify the connection

```
telnet localhost 9999
```

Replace localhost with IP. Type anything on these telnet connection and you should get response properly.
Also you can check on server.py cmd prompt for the connections made.

And as I mentioned, check [this link](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/).

Comment: I dont you understand my question. I am not having trouble getting a connection. I am trying to have the server.py perform task while still communicating with clients. Here is an example that I want it to do: while there are clients connected I want the server to check a log file and if it changes I want it to send a message to the clients

Comment: I have updated answer to include code to send message to clients accordingly but you need to update logic for file changing for yourself.

Comment: Updated code to send message when file changes. Try changing file and you should get message as 'File Changed'.

Comment: Ok thats more what I was looking for, is it possible to still accept messages from the client as well?

Comment: yes you can add `data = clientsock.recv(1024)` or BUFF in your case in  outer while and then you this in inner while.

Comment: sorry im having trouble getting it to work as expected, where would I put `data = conn.recv(1024) print data` in your example?

Comment: accept messages from client and do what with it? Just reply back to client? Please see edited.

Comment: Im just trying to print it for now, with your edited code I only am able to send one message to the server and it gets stuck in the `while True:
        logfile = open("serverlog.txt","r")` loop